# Write Byte Array to a file JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, rest, download, xmlhttprequest

I have Java REST webservice that returns documents as byte array, I need to write JavaScript code to get the webservice's response and write it to a file in order to download that file as PDF Kindly see a screen shot of the webservice's response and see my sample code this code downloads a corrupted PDF file.

```js
var data = new FormData();
data.append('PARAM1', 'Value1');
data.append('PARAM2', 'Value2');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'SERVICEURL');
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
xhr.onload = function() {
    
    console.log('Response text = ' + xhr.responseText);
    console.log('Returned status = ' + xhr.status);
    
    
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(xhr.responseText);

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arr);
    var a = window.document.createElement('a');
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(byteArray, { type: 'application/octet-stream' }));
    a.download = "tst.pdf";
    // Append anchor to body.
    document.body.appendChild(a)
    a.click();
    // Remove anchor from body
    document.body.removeChild(a)
    
};
xhr.send(data);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are requesting a binary file you need to tell XHR about that otherwise it will use the default "text" (UTF-8) encoding that will interpret pdf as text and will mess up the encoding. Just assign `responseType` property a value of 'blob' or the MIME type of pdf

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob'; // tell XHR that the response will be a pdf file

// OR xhr.responseType = 'application/pdf'; if above doesn't work
```

And you will access it using `response` property and not `responseText`.
So you will use `arr.push(xhr.response);` and it will return you a Blob.

If this doesn't work, inform me will update another solution.

Update:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob'; // tell XHR that the response will be a pdf file
xhr.onload = function() {
    var blob = this.response;
    var a = window.document.createElement('a');
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.download = "tst.pdf";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
};
```

Comment: Hi Viney thanks for help I've tried your idea but I received the following error 
"The provided value 'application/pdf' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType"

Comment: Are fetching just one pdf or multiple?

Comment: just one document

Comment: Thanks It is working using your sample code, thanks very much

Comment: Cool..that was nothing.

Comment: Hi I have another issue related to the same task, I'm forced to use a webservice that returns JSON object and inside that json I will find the document byte array as an object, how can i download this document using this webservice

Comment: File file = new File(path);
            bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];

            //read file into bytes[]
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(bytesArray);
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject();
responseObject .put("document",bytesArray);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179277/discussion-between-user1814595-and-viney).