# How to answer call with valid base64 encoded .zip-Files in Ktor?

Tags: javascript, base64, backend, blob, ktor

In my Ktor backend I would like to download entire folders on request. The zipping works fine, and I send the file to the client with call.respondFile(). The zip folder created in the backend can be unzipped without any errors and contains the correct files, so archiving on the backend side is not the problem. Now on the client side there are several problems:

1. the base64 string I get from Ktor is always malformed. I have to remove line breaks, spaces and special characters that (for whatever reason) are contained in it.
2. even if all base64 validators on the internet recognize the string as valid, it is not possible to use JavaScripts 'atob', as it still seem to contain invalid characters?

I have already discovered many similar (javascript) problems here on stack overflow, but it seems to me that the error is not on the JavaScript side, but in the way Ktor outputs a file with respondFile. The Ktor documentation is unfortunately not very helpful here. Here is my backend code (handleArchiveDownload returns a Java File object):

Routing:

```kotlin
val archive = fileHandler.handleArchiveDownload(gameId)
if (archive != null) {
    call.response.header(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, ContentDisposition.Attachment.withParameter(ContentDisposition.Parameters.FileName, "game_archive.zip").toString())
    call.respondFile(archive)
} else {
    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Something went wrong creating your .zip-archive. Please check the server logs.")
}
```

This is an example of a string I receive with this call, try to decode it yourself:

```
PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0000Mt�W\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\n\u00005\u0000index.htmlUT\r\u0000\u0007�'�e�'�e�'�e\n\u0000 \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0018\u0000�@7i�8�\u0001���p�8�\u0001�@7i�8�\u0001�TMo�8\u0010��W�u�ű6=�A6�&�ǢE\u00038٢GZ\u001c�SQ#��l�\u007ff/�\u001bz��\u007flgD;�\u0016�`\u000f�(�|3ｙ�&��o\u001e��߁K�_\\T�\u0002o��\u0017\u0016��\u0005@��X]Ȳ�d�v&DL�������\u0005��?�t8/���M\u001fR\u0001u�\tY\u000e��&7���\u001a/Ǐ)\u0010S\"�/cm<ίf���\u0012%��w�\u0006�dB�H\t�2o�#����~^���1:D\t�\u0002��Ŭ\u001c�fu�\u0007̪<�V�}:`���\u0017���\u000e\u0019�\u000f`�\u0018;`\u001c�{�!�\u0013�yu8��o��\u0001��\t��\u001d�z'\u001f�&!�M'�\rzc�g�*\u001ci\u0001<v`Ṁ��C�6�N�\t��)��\u001f��S�(!�\u0000�\u000f\u001bc\u0002�\u00127x@Z��]�\u0015�#a\u0004KA\u001e���;���\u0008\u0003�>4���>Q#��v�L�<��,m�0�{-�\u0008>5��������сӇh\"�\u0011nU\u0001 M\\b�\u0011�D����JT�:��S��ck���p\u0006����\u0010k\u0017\u0008W\"��\u0016Xs\u0001Qt�#�j�A���R)�s�5�a�\")�:\u0018\u0011\u001an�ؔ.���� \u000fX;�}ߨ{;�����)�,�\u001a�\u000c�\u000f�5�:�&�\u0016�\u000eY-~!�k5I\u001d6�z��ǜ���Xi3�\u000c��\u0014��M����v�\"�\u000f��F��^�\r̥\"�\t�( �F��\u0011�Ul���g\u0018KO,Y�y>\u0003��<R�ճ\u0013×x��x-�\u0006W��\u001ek�Ug�g��+\u0010��\u0016\u001e��r}�a�=\u001e�Tk\"W�\u0019dG�~�E���C\u0007ڢ\u0003�wqP\u0014S?�gv_tr\u0004\t�^V\u0003���H���&\u0019�g5#�UL�,F�sN�o\u0007�\u0015I���?3��c�T�sK���S[~�1���%���ӎ�\u0016=ON=\u0018si�P�\u0010;(X,�2�ȓ,\u000f0��qf�\u0003PK\u0007\u0008u]�i�\u0002\u0000\u0000�\u0005\u0000\u0000PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0000Mt�W\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\t\u00005\u0000style.cssUT\r\u0000\u0007�'�e�'�e�'�e\n\u0000 \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0018\u0000K+8i�8�\u0001�&�p�8�\u0001K+8i�8�\u0001uQ�n�0\u0010��\u0015�z�%��V9�S>�����\u0003�&\u0001U���\r!����왝��u��B�+���.Q�,��#�k\u0000f\u000eG\u0012��4�\u0000�R�zƿ��'':�ְ��\u0004��\u0007�8�+`Y\u0018�u�^�#\u0013\u0002ܰ�\u0005��0�RF�+�OT@�<�G%���[9f`p\u0014��\u0011\t�\u000c+�9�\u0004j�\u001c�G�/�%\u000c\u001a���o�R=�J7G�[��m�g�Jm\u0013&9'Z�^�P8n����\u000e\"鎜�z��\u0017e܀�t��t.�&��2\u0010\u0013�i1��e�]^\n/)\u0006v��E����̓<\u001d�}�� m\u0011\t�m��l\n��9^H�g\u001a5\u0013�ޑv�K�1z�o�L\tB\u0006\u001a��\t����\u001f?PK\u0007\u0008�y��*\u0001\u0000\u00004\u0002\u0000\u0000PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0000Mt�W\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007\u00005\u0000main.jsUT\r\u0000\u0007�'�e�'�e�'�e\n\u0000 \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0018\u0000ky8i�8�\u0001�&�p�8�\u0001ky8i�8�\u0001+��K�/�����OLQ�U�M�����J+�K.��σ�\u0015��\u0014� 9?�8?'U/'?]C�#1''_!<5�DQIӚ�\u0016\u0000PK\u0007\u0008\u0000�q&E\u0000\u0000\u0000J\u0000\u0000\u0000PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0000�y�W\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000b\u00005\u0000archive.zipUT\r\u0000\u0007\u00141�e�0�e\u00141�e\n\u0000 \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0018\u0000�,i��8�\u0001(�Ʈ�8�\u0001�,i��8�\u0001\u000b�ff\u0011a���`�-�\u001d΀\u0004�\u0018L\u00192�RR+�2JrsBCx\u0019�\u001f����\u0007b\u0010�Š\u0000V�� ����<��-Ɲ7�\u0014�h\u0018�7�7�������=�/�n4�}�h6A���E��\u00167\u0017�G�t\u0007\u0007*7/�YR���[������t\u0017�ob�\t�M\u001a]5����\\��}~�ܾ{�\u001b���Ǆ�b��1S\\��(���\u000b\u0011�'6\u001dNYP������Ǉo��g����f�����ݾ�A���9#�ޟP3߾c����~M�`���ɹ6�֧�{@H������t�S�\u0007�j�����v�6��\u001d����ʅ�\u0005Ӻ�G��|O+�a?���ӊ���V\t;V\u001f\u0015����n>�}�\t\u0013%�\u0013d�T�T�\"����b����یs:9w���R�.�MM��oު��W�d2\u0019m�\u0012|ϴ/|�|��_\u0007���[~˟9\u0011��MC�\rC\u0013�t2�\u001d!�\n���+c\u007f��WNd�v�k�~�zI�\u0003\u000e�#v&��޷\u000bT^��l��*�\r�tr�\r�V�\u001e�3=����\u007f\u000f�O_l�ܞ��P0/�Q�7&��q�\u001bG�\u001e�\n�j��?�cRr����\u0002�-�w\u001e\u0012�\u0016�\u0008W:y@,��1���v�%s�\u0004i�/�i�1�GI��JBP*oύ)z[׬���\u001fa�����j��\u001e^>�yGg��\u007f�7��MO[]P;(v�/R�N�?��S��pժ{��\u001c�{+\"�x1��?\"[��.Z��P�'���k��=�t5�4\uf665J�8�j(�u[�G�whN��\u007f�\u0012��:�/+��|�\tz{u����\u0015\u007foW�^d\u000bo~$�� 4�#��#m��s��zz�j�'β��\u000e�V\n?\"�⾳��-��o-b�\\^\u0018 \u0012l�?�,�����t\\\u0018����<��]�&y#�T�W��e\u001d�\u007f�~���g�z�y���xũ��!O��O��\u0011\u001c]�����#��\u001e�]�{%f��g+Q�y4ീ�F��*��'&��\u001b�<]���9����4�~�k&\u0006�#�\u000c\u000c\u00018�\u0015'0_\u0015�T��%\u0017\u0017��V��\u0016�ltS�(8[������\r\u0004�|\u0016�VuB��!�rB���\u001f�ۿ2�Tc\u000c��}\u001d��ۅ\u000b���9w����G��i7���\u0017xTg�R��l�4>w���&�\u0018^\u0005m�:��큺�էk\u001b��g�~����s�H�\u0003�K��+\u000b3��p���E�-An紧��8L�itW�6gM�eZB�Ȥ-��/'�h\u007f�<ʒ�P��\u000f���<R\u001b����\u0015d����}Qt���7���r��,գ��m\r���9��\u0017>��}s^W��/�z�ar��G%zK�6_5\u0012\u0010��4��,uJl\u001c��&[��=��~O�s��F�{��[\n���;rW������2��}����{\u0013��x�1�j������&5������g��A�r�r�.-F\u0006\u0006\u0013&|��\u000e�����<�,�q�]�\u001a'0���3�'���>\u007f���O���\u0013�g�\\���K�����3�?���)Ҡ`i���^=T_�>������z����r�@�˳V�1���0�P�\u0015h�\u0017\u0003�s�T�:�\u001b��Ģ�̲T���\u0002��E\u000c{Rw\u0019���hd'O��|r\u000e�D���ցh\u0018\u001f\u0000PK\u0007\u0008�<�k\u0005\u0000\u0000�\u0005\u0000\u0000PK\u0001\u0002\u0014\u0000\u0014\u0000\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0000Mt�Wu]�i�\u0002\u0000\u0000�\u0005\u0000\u0000\n\u0000-\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000index.htmlUT\u0005\u0000\u0007�'�e\n\u0000 \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0018\u0000�@7i�8�\u0001���p�8�\u0001�@7i�8�\u0001PK\u0001\u0002\u0014\u0000\u0014\u0000\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0000Mt�W�y��*\u0001\u0000\u00004\u0002\u0000\u0000\t\u0000-\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000X\u0003\u0000\u0000style.cssUT\u0005\u0000\u0007�'�e\n\u0000 \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0018\u0000K+8i�8�\u0001�&�p�8�\u0001K+8i�8�\u0001PK\u0001\u0002\u0014\u0000\u0014\u0000\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0000Mt�W\u0000�q&E\u0000\u0000\u0000J\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007\u0000-\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0004\u0000\u0000main.jsUT\u0005\u0000\u0007�'�e\n\u0000 \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0018\u0000ky8i�8�\u0001�&�p�8�\u0001ky8i�8�\u0001PK\u0001\u0002\u0014\u0000\u0014\u0000\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0000�y�W�<�k\u0005\u0000\u0000�\u0005\u0000\u0000\u000b\u0000-\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0005\u0000\u0000archive.zipUT\u0005\u0000\u0007\u00141�e\n\u0000 \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0018\u0000�,i��8�\u0001(�Ʈ�8�\u0001�,i��8�\u0001PK\u0005\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004\u0000\u0004\u0000�\u0001\u0000\u0000v\u000b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000
```

So my questions are:

Is call.respondFile() the wrong thing to use? Why does Ktor send malformed base64 strings that I have to fix in JavaScript first, only to realize that the file is damaged? Maybe someone can show me an example of how to send a .zip file with Ktor?

I'm stuck and would really appreciate any help.
Kind regards.

Comment: Can you please explain why do you send a response with the Base64 string instead with the binary data? The `ApplicationCall.respondFile` method calling is a correct approach.

Comment: That is not on purpose, that is just what I receive from `ApplicationCall.respondFile`. I do not encode the file beforehand. Can you perhaps provide an example of how to send binary data?

Comment: Using the `ApplicationCall.respondFile` method, you can respond with binary data. To receive it, you can use the code from this article (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest_API/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data), just replace the usage of `XMLHttpRequest` with `fetch`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Ktor did everything as intended, the issue was indeed that I did not specify the correct response type in JavaScript. This post also helped a lot:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132798/write-byte-array-to-a-file-javascript